# Implementing a graph in either C++ or Java

Tags: java, c++, graph

What's the best ways of implementing a graph in either C++ or Java? In C++, I was thinking about using a 2d array to do it. In java, I was considering an arrayList.

Comment: There are lots of graph representations that can be done in one language or the other (or both). What do you want to do with the representation? Search? Test whether it's connected? Compute it's chromatic number? Something else? Without knowing what you want to do with the representation, it's impossible to say what representation is best.

Comment: Do you have to implement it yourself, or can you use a library?

Comment: I have to implement it myself. And the reason that I want a graph, is so that I can use the minimal spanning tree algorithm.

Comment: If this is homework, please flag it as such? It just seems like a homework question, that's all. My apologies if it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, language choices aren't the most massive issue in the world, in my opinion. Unless you have a requirement to use a specific language or on portability, using either C++ or Java will be sufficient. Having said that, your question seems somewhat homework-ish. Are you using [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) for your MST implementation?

As other answers have already said, there are a few ways to represent graphs. The two that I'm most familiar with for representing graphs are:

1. An [Adjacency Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), which is a 2D array where each "row" and "column" is a node, and a value at that position of the matrix indicates an edge (or an edge weight) and a null-value (or a 0-value, or some other sentinel/meaningful value) indicates no edge
2. An [Adjacency List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), which is a 2D array (kinda), where the *i*-th list is the list of all the nodes that are connected to (adjacent to) node *i*. At times, you may also choose to make the list a list of pairs of node names and edge weights, if your graph is directed/weighted.

In the adjacency list article on Wikipedia (linked above) there is a section on tradeoffs between the two representations.

On the subject of the MST algorithm:

You will probably get better performance using an adjacency list, out of the top of my head, but that's only theoretically (I think?). Implementation-wise, there are things such as locality of reference to take into account. I would personally prefer, for ease of coding, however, to use an adjacency matrix (I just personally find them easier to work with, especially on weighted graphs), unless there's a need for really good performance.

Adjacency Matrix (C++):

```
vector<vector<int> > adj_Mat(n, vector<int>(n, 0));
```

where *n* is the number of nodes in the graph. Then `adj_Mat[i][j]` is the weight of the edge between nodes *i* and *j*.

Adjacency List (C++):

```
vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > adj_list(n);
```

Then, if the *i*-th node has an edge weight of *k* to node *j*, I'd do something like this (assuming the graph is directed)

```
adj_list[i].push_back(pair<int, int>(j, k));
```

Now, my C++ is really hacky because I tend to use it for hacking random code in coding competitions, so this isn't really good code but it's really basic ways to code up these data representations.

Sorry about the massive rant, and I hope it does help.

Comment: +1...I think sparcity is an important factor to consider when choosing between the matrix and the list.

Comment: @prelic: But couldn't you just use a sparse matrix? It'd be just as efficient as a list, I would have thought.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 conventional ways to represent a graph.

1. Adjacency matrix: meaning if you got n nodes then you got a matrix of n by n with matrix[i, j] indicates if there is an edge between the nodes (usually with a boolean or int if you want weights)
2. Adjacency list: have an collection for each node which indicates the nodes that it has edges to.

For the first approach a 2d array is the best, for the second I would go with an HashSet (or HashMap if you want weights)

When choosing one over the other you need to consider the graph size, the number of edges vs number of nodes and what algorithm you are going to run on it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html). There is a learning phase, but once you get it you will never look back.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is faster than Java. And if you want to create a good graph, you should make your own type with fields you need (for example weight of graph's nodes). You also should create a Node class, which contains it's attributes and list of other nodes to which it's connected.
In Graph you should have list of it's nodes, its attributes and functions (for example bool isFlat()).
I think it's a better way to implement graph than 2D array or ArrayList.

Comment: I don't think you really need to draw graphs in real time, so I don't think speed would be a problem for him.

Comment: And even though it's better because then you can use and extend it if one day you need to.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to implement graphs `G=(V,E)` depends on the properties of these graphs and what kind of operations you tend to perform on them. Generally speaking, for sparse graphs, i.e. graphs where `|E| << |V|^2`, one usually chooses adjacency lists (slower, but memory-efficient). For graphs with `|E| =~ |V|^2`, adjacency matrices are usually better (faster, but memory-intensive).

Depending on what exactly you intend to do with your graphs, other approaches might be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

If you need fast algorithm use array-based approach in C++.
But if you write algorithm, that should be read by other people use OOP-based approach in Java.

Comment: Or use an OOP-based approach in C++. (You might need to rethink your categorization of C++ as being fast vs. Java as being readable.)

Comment: I don't wanna argue about this, but i mean that Java readability much better than C++ for NOT programmer.