# Using adjaceny matrix to solve graph problems

Tags: c++, graph, adjacency-matrix

I was just wondering how you can use and adjacency matrix to solve graph problems.

For example for my program I have an exchange rate for two items.

Input to build a directed graph: 6 shirts 15 socks
Input to build a directed graph: 2 socks 1 underwear

Directed graph:

shirts --(6/15)-- socks --(2/1)-- underwear

So the edge from shirts to socks is 6, edge from socks to shirts is 15, socks to underwear is 2 and underwear to socks is 1.

Input to compare: socks shirts 
Solution : 15 socks 6 shirts

Input to compare: shirts underwear
Soltuion : 12 shirts 15 underwear

My question is how can I represent this with an adjacency matrix and be able to get its weight to solve the problem.

I was thinking of having an adjacency matrix that would look like this for the above problem.

```
          shirts   socks  underwear
shirts    [ 0       6     0 ]
socks     [ 15      0     2 ]
underwear [ 0       1     0 ]
```

Is this a good start? I'm trying to get the logic before the code.

Just looking for some more information on how to do this on a bigger scale with more items and separate graphs.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the issue at hand, but I don't see a graph here. What are your vertices? socks and shirts? and what are your edges? which graph-algorithm do you want to apply on these?

Comment: @amit: I think the OP wants to view it as a bipartite graph with one color of vertices as shirts and one color as socks.

Comment: What @amit said. What kind of graph are you trying to build? I can't even see what problem you're solving at the moment, to be honest. You might need a clearer example to show what you're trying to solve and how you'd use an adjacency matrix.

Comment: Yes my vertices would be socks and shirts and the edge would be 6/15 going from shirts to socks or 15/6 going from socks to shirts. I really don't know any graph-algorithms so I'm trying to figure out what would be the easiest.

Comment: @Claud25: What are you trying to achieve? What should be the output of your algorithm? If you just want to store data, I don't think a graph is the right solution here. You might want a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) or a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) [`map<item,int>`]

Comment: @amit I'm just trying to get the exchange rate for two items. I edited my example to where it now included underwear and it compares shirts to underwear. My teacher said we can also use a map but I've never done anything with a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you a basic hint on what is an adjacency graph. Solving your problem is your homework so I cannot do it.

Imagine the following graph:

```
    A-----B
   / \   | \
  /   \  |  \
 /     \ |   \
C-------D-----E
```

An adjacency matrix tells which node in the graph is connected to which:

```
    A  B  C  D  E
A [ 0  1  1  1  0 ]
B [ 1  0  0  1  1 ]
C [ 1  0  0  1  0 ]
D [ 1  1  1  0  1 ]
E [ 0  1  0  1  0 ]
```

For example entry (D, E) shows that D and E are connected, while (A, E) shows that A and E are not. Note that this matrix is symmetric because the graph is undirected.

If the matrix is weighted as follows:

```
    A--3--B
   / \   | \
  5   3  2  1
 /     \ |   \
C---2---D--7--E
```

then the adjacency matrix shows which are connected and with what weight (assuming 0 shows no connection):

```
    A  B  C  D  E
A [ 0  3  5  3  0 ]
B [ 3  0  0  2  1 ]
C [ 5  0  0  2  0 ]
D [ 3  2  2  0  7 ]
E [ 0  1  0  7  0 ]
```

In your case, your graph is a bunch of nodes having edges to a bunch of other nodes. Your adjacency matrix would look very similar to what you have already come up with, but the values might not be correct. The values should be either the same, negative of each other or 1 over the other, depending on what your algorithm is going to be.

Comment: I think for my problem I am using a directed graph which is the reason I have 6/15 since from shirts to socks the edge is 6 and from socks to shirts the edge would be 15.

Comment: I don't really know your problem, what these weights represent or what you need to compute, so I can't really what values should be there. That would be part of your homework solution I guess.

Comment: What I'm trying to compute is the exchange rate so 6 shirts would be worth 15 pairs of socks. Your graph really helped me out either way. If I wanted to compare the exchange rate between shirts and socks then 6 shirts would be worth 15 pairs of socks. If I wanted the exchange rate between socks and shirts then 15 pairs of socks are worth 6 shirts. I don't know if that makes sense but like I said either way your answer helped thus far.

Comment: @Claud25, yeah I understand. I have seen similar problems with currency.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922832/implementing-a-graph-in-either-c-or-java/8923072#8923072) was a previous SO post I wrote about how you could represent graphs, using Adjacency Matrices or Adjacency Lists.

It discusses solving the [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) graph problem and which of the data structures would be appropriate for solving the problem. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your graph problem, but this would be a starting point as to how you represent graphs. I'll try and edit my answer if you add more information.